# c assignment a int to 0xFFFFFFFF, but get 0

Tags: c, bit

I want to calculate a mask to perform logical right shift, this is my code:

```
int mask;
int arl = x >> n;
mask = ~((~0) << (32 - n));
return arl & mask;
```

when `n` equals to `0`, I think mask should be `0xFFFFFFFF`, but it didn't work. I used gdb to debug, and got this:

```
(gdb) p/t  ~((~0) << (32 - n))
$2 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
(gdb) p/t  mask
$3 = 0
```

Why mask is `0`?

Comment: Use unsigned types for bit manipulations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* if `int` is 32-bit long or shorter.

Quote fron [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Try this: `mask = n >= 32 ? ~0 : ~((~0) << (32 - n));`

Answer (score 0):

```
You are doing undefine behavior if int is 32-bit.
mask = (1 << 32); // it is undefine behaviour

then 1's complement of 0 is -1 ( ~0 ----> FFFFFFFF ).
try this:       
  int mask;
  int n = 1; // if n = 1;
  mask = ~((~0) << (32 - n)); 
  //~((-1) << (32 - 1)) ----> ~(FFFFFFFF << 31) 
  // 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 
  //   7    F    F    F    F    F    F    F
  printf("%x\n",mask); // output is 7FFF FFFF
  printf("%d\n"); // output is 2147483647
```

Comment: Thank you, when n is 0 , i think is a special case, i set mask = -1 to get it work.